# Compress/expand sound from Mp3 files in Linux server/terminal?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, python-3.x, audio, mp3

In a python script on my Ubuntu server, i need to process many incoming mp3 audio files with sound compressor. E.g. a tool that reduces difference between the most quiet and most loud sound levels.

Is that possible? I believe i don't need to write a program for this.

If so, what utility i should use and how do i configure it?

Comment: @Cyrus i understand, but why are you suggesting that?

Comment: _Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic._ Maybe someone is willing to help you in a bounty.

Comment: I think that you should see http://askubuntu.com/questions/246242/how-to-normalize-sound-in-mp3-files - some of the answers should give you clues about what to install and how to execute the command line tools (which arguments to use).

Comment: @wojciii there is a difference between compression and normalization. Compression is a dynamic process that heavily affects the output audio. It used on radiostations, record studios, etc. Normalization is a process of just fixing the peaks to be at 0 dB (http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22797/how-is-compression-different-from-normalization). Normalization is not really needed for me, but i need to compress&gain voice recordings to hear anything better, which comes to my server. **aergistal** answer seems correct, will check it.

Comment: It's interesting why people downvote this question. I had a bit of explosion of negative votes on my question on **meta** related to votes on SO today, for now think that i should leave SO and never login back because i feel that it becomes really inappropriate for me to accept this strange voting behavior which is meaningless for anyone but important for positioning, relevance and search on site. Feeling sad, i am not that stupid to be touched by someone's downvote, i really don't care on reputation, but it's not only about me, many people get under rules of this incorrect ranking system.

Comment: The question is off topic, as per the guidelines - that is probably why the downvotes occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) has a filter for compressing or expanding the audio’s dynamic range called `compand`. You can exec it from within your Python script. Check the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#compand) for usage examples.

Random example (for audio with whisper and explosion parts):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "compand=0|0:1|1:-90/-900|-70/-70|-30/-9|0/-3:6:0:0:0" output.mp3
```

meaning:
attack 0, decay 1, points -90/900, -70/-70, -30/-9. 0/-3, soft-knee 6, gain 0, volume 0, delay 0

To install it you can `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` or compile it from source to get the latest features.

Answer (score 1):

If you're merely looking for "a tool that reduces difference between the most quiet and most loud sound levels" then it sounds like you're looking for [dynamic range compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression), though I'd suggest you also investigate [ReplayGain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain), which determines the optimal loudness level for an audio track (as opposed to making the soft parts louder and the loud parts softer).  For most uses, ReplayGain is preferable, though if you have hearing problems or merely want to maximize people's ability to understand a sound clip (rather than *enjoying* it), range compression makes more sense.

There are two ways to do either of these tasks: permanently and via metadata:

### Permanently

This involves decompressing the audio, modifying it, and re-encoding it.  **You will lose audio quality** because MP3 is [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), though this would be a minor hit if you use the exact same encoder at the exact same software version and the exact same configuration.  The fact that you must re-encode will also make this process significantly slower.

### Via metadata

There is software out there that can evaluate your library and stick ReplayGain measurements into your media's metadata (in the case of MP3, this would be as an ID3 tag). Players that understand this format can then adjust the volume levels as you play the audio sample.  This is non-destructive and you will lose nothing.  It's also faster since you don't need to compress the audio back into an MP3.

There are plenty of [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain#Implementations) to choose from, at least for ReplayGain.

Comment: Do you understand that original question was about `linux` and `python`?

Comment: Yes. I also saw `bash` listed, which implies you're not exclusively looking for a python library. If you followed my last link, you'd find [rgain](https://bitbucket.org/fk/rgain), which is a python RG tool that may do exactly what you want.

Comment: @rgain currently your answer looks as a long theory with a link to wikipedia, not an implementation actually even (in that section there is no link to any scripts). I've found this project https://bitbucket.org/fk/rgain (not directly) but **aergistal** answer still looks better than yours. Also, http://www.bobulous.org.uk/misc/Replay-Gain-in-Linux.html link is much more useful.

Comment: That other answer reencodes the MP3 and therefore loses quality. I put all that "theory" in my answer to address the pros and cons. Similarly, I had to explain ReplayGain vs range compression. It seems from your comments that you want range compression. If you also want it to be destructive, `ffmpeg` is one of the better options. Though do note that `ffmpeg` has its own MP3 encoder that is (iirc) inferior to [LAME](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=LAME), so you may lose more quality than you'd want (output as .wav and then use LAME to minimize quality loss, or try a higher bitrate).

Comment: @AdamKatz You're mistaken, `ffmpeg` doesn't have a native mp3 encoder at all and it uses `libmp3lame` aka LAME. Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3.

Comment: @AdamKatz you cannot bypass re-encoding when edit files in any useful way